# A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument ''User\desktop\sample_project_1\env'

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda

I've just installed miniconda and after installing some packages, I was prompted to run this line:

```
To activate this environment, use

     $ conda activate C:\Users\Main User\desktop\sample_project_1\env
```

However, when I run it I receive this error:

```
Enter-CondaEnvironment : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument
'User\desktop\sample_project_1\env'.
At C:\Users\Main User\miniconda3\shell\condabin\Conda.psm1:170 char:17
+                 Enter-CondaEnvironment @OtherArgs;
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Enter-CondaEnvironment], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Enter-CondaEnvironment
```

Can someone help me identify the problem please?

Comment: try with some quotes around the path: `conda activate "C:\Users\Main User\desktop\sample_project_1\env"`. since there is a space in your path, the CLI considers it as two params if it is not wrapped into quotes

Comment: That's solved it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score -1):

Solution:

```
conda activate "C:\Users\Main User\desktop\sample_project_1\env"
```

Comment: You were actually prompted to do so by Miniconda. What was your contibuted solution? Did you just follow the Miniconda prompt?